# low display resolution

Tags: 14.04, xorg, display-resolution, xrandr

I have a problem with my new desktop: low display resolution.

Here is some simple info of my desktop pc.
os: ubuntu 14.04 LTS
display card:   nvidia gtx 960

I have searched a lot of solutions on Internet but none of them seems to work for me. And here are what I have tried.

### Step1.

I have downloaded the latest nvidia driver for gtx 960 and install it via ubuntu ***software & updates***.
**I think the driver works** because 2 two more display resolution were added(1360*768 & 1152*864) to my monitor while only 1024*768 & 800*600 were listed before. Besides, NVIDIA X Server Settings is available now. However, the problem is not solved.

### Step2.

I tried to add a display resolution by using **xrandr** command. Following commands were executed:

```
joey@joey-B85M:~$ cvt 1680 1050 60
# 1680x1050 59.95 Hz (CVT 1.76MA) hsync: 65.29 kHz; pclk: 146.25 MHz
Modeline "1680x1050_60.00"  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync
```

```
joey@joey-B85M:~$ xrandr --newmode "1680x1050_60.00"  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240 1050 
1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync
```

Then I executed `xrandr` command and the output is this:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1152 x 864, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 connected primary 1152x864+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0 +
   1360x768       60.0     59.8

   1152x864       60.0* 
   800x600        72.2     60.3     56.2

   680x384        60.0     59.8

   640x480        59.9

   512x384        60.0

   400x300        72.2

   320x240        60.1

DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  1680x1050_60.00 (0x1f9)  146.2MHz
        h: width  1680 start 1784 end 1960 total 2240 skew    0 clock   65.3KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1089           clock   60.0Hz
```

As you can see, I guess the point is that: ***I am adding a new display resolution to a display card which I am not actually using.*** I add 1680x1050_60.00 to **DVI-D-0**, the display card I should have in use. But actually, I am using **DVI-I-0**.

I searched again and think it may be a problem of xrog.conf, and tried to generate one. I run this:

```
Xorg -configure: 1
```

Here is the output:

```
X.Org X Server 1.17.1
Release Date: 2015-02-10
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-77-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux joey-B85M 3.19.0-49-generic #55~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 22 11:24:31 UTC 2016 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-49-generic root=UUID=94912055-e1da-4c3e-bd80-6d1b7209d320 ro drm.debug=0xe plymouth:debug
Build Date: 13 May 2015  04:35:05AM
xorg-server 2:1.17.1-0ubuntu3~trusty1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.1.log", Time: Tue Feb  9 16:15:51 2016
List of video drivers:
    siliconmotion
    intel
    r128
    sisusb
    vmware
    trident
    nvidia
    tdfx
    nouveau
    mga
    mach64
    radeon
    ati
    neomagic
    cirrus
    openchrome
    savage
    vesa
    fbdev
    modesetting
(++) Using config file: "/home/joey/xorg.conf.new"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
```

Xorg detected your mouse at device /dev/input/mice.
Please check your config if the mouse is still not
operational, as by default Xorg tries to autodetect
the protocol.

Your xorg.conf file is /home/joey/xorg.conf.new

To test the server, run 'X -config /home/joey/xorg.conf.new'

(EE) Server terminated with error (2). Closing log file.

Unfortunately, another error. Here is my xorg.conf.new file.

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection
```

Section "Files"
    ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
    FontPath     "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load  "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Keyboard0"
    Driver      "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Mouse0"
    Driver      "mouse"
    Option      "Protocol" "auto"
    Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor0"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "nvidia"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "Card0"
    Monitor    "Monitor0"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

What should I do ? Will connecting to **DVI-D-0** solve the problem? If so, how can I do this?
By the way, how to post file in askubuntu.com ? So much post code is rather ugly.

EDIT: Output of command

```
lscpci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
```

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1401 (rev a1)
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device 36be
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 output of this cmd was added

Comment: @joeyX Didn't you try to install/upgrade nvidia driver?

Comment: @MicrosoftLinux yes, I did. I installed latest nvidia driver for gtx 960

Comment: @joeyX   I faced this problem many times and always solved with [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/676956/problem-with-nvidia-driver-on-msi-cx623/676973#676973) method. See if it may help you.

Comment: @MicrosoftLinux Thx, I will take a try and confirm whether I missed some info of my problem